# canOpenURL: Always Fails

Tags: xcode, swift2, nsurlrequest, viber

I'm always getting this response even I already add it to my *LSApplicationQueriesSchemes*

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
        <string>viber</string>
        <string>whatsapp</string>
    </array>
```

I execute my code like this

```
let viberUrl = NSURL( string: "viber://forward?text=Hello")!

      if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(viberUrl) {
        print("app installed")
      }
```

And xcode logs:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "viber://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme viber"
```

I can open viber app using my app but I also want to test if the app is installed or not.

Any clue where did I get wrong? Or do I miss something?
My test device iphone 5s with iOS 9.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this

```
let mainViberUrl = NSURL(string: "viber://")!
let viberUrl = NSURL( string: "viber://forward?text=Hello")!

if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(mainViberUrl) {
    print("app installed")
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openUrl(viberUrl)
}
```

I think it's better to do it like my code, cause `forward?text=Hello"` the query part of the NSURL produce an error which causes `canOpenURL` to return false.

**Note:** This works with mine btw

Here's a link that might help you better understand this
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl/